# Restrict duplicate item in Rubaxa ng-sortable list

Tags: angularjs, rubaxa-sortable

I have two set of lists, list A and list B. **I want to restrict duplicate items from list A to be dropped into list B.** List A is configured to clone its items. I am using AngularJS with sortable (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable).

Here are my two configs:

```
$scope._listAConfig = {
    group: { name: 'listA', pull: 'clone', put: false }
};

$scope._listBConfig = {
    group: { name: 'listB', pull: false, put: ['listA'] }
};
```

Comment: Did you find how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

in sortable github issues  - 
[issue 205](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/205)
  - they provide an example:
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/funukuveli/1/edit?html,js,output) , look at second and third list. I guess it's what you're trying to achieve. Looking at example if I were you I would write it that way:

```
$scope.listA = ['foo 1', 'foo 2'];
    $scope._listAConfig = { 
            group: {
              name: 'listA',
              pull: 'clone'
            }
    };      

    $scope.listB = ['bar 1', 'bar 2'];
    $scope._listBConfig = { 
             group: {
               name: 'listB',
               put: ['listA']
             }
    };
```